# Extract value of attribute node via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I extract the value of an attribute node via XPath?

A sample XML file is:

```
<parents name='Parents'>
  <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'>
    <Children name='Children'>
      <child name='Child_2' id='2'>child2_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_4' id='4'>child4_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_1' id='3'>child1_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_3' id='1'>child3_Parent_1</child>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
  <Parent id='2' name='Parent_2'>
    <Children name='Children'>
      <child name='Child_1' id='8'>child1_parent2</child>
      <child name='Child_2' id='7'>child2_parent2</child>
      <child name='Child_4' id='6'>child4_parent2</child>
      <child name='Child_3' id='5'>child3_parent2</child>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
</parents>
```

So far I have this XPath string:

```
//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child[@name]
```

It returns only `child` elements, but I would like to have the value of the `name` attribute.

For my sample XML file, here's what I'd like the output to be:

```
Child_2
Child_4
Child_1
Child_3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting attribute using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Answer (score 417, accepted):

```
//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/@name
```

Your original `child[@name]` means an element `child` which has an attribute `name`. You want `child/@name`.

Comment: I agree, the question was how to get the value of the attribute

Comment: What if i would like to extract only the value/description/data present in between the tags ....

Answer (score 181):

To get just the value (without attribute names), use `string()`:

`string(//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/@name)`

The [fn:string()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string) fucntion will return the value of its argument as `xs:string`. In case its argument is an attribute, it will therefore return the attribute's value as `xs:string`.

Comment: With `xqilla` it was necessary to call `xs:string`. I wonder why.

Comment: @krlmlr Probably `xs` is the namespace prefix for the XPath functions. So they are not mixed up with others.

Comment: LOL.  This is the only answer that actually answers the question.  +1

Comment: This will provide only the first hit in xmllint

Comment: What if I have a list of attributes and I need their values? string() seems to return just the first value.

Comment: For me, it only worked this way: `//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/string(@name)`

Answer (score 10):

As answered above:

```
//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/@name
```

will only output the `name` attribute of the 4 `child` nodes belonging to the `Parent` specified by its predicate `[@id=1]`. You'll then need to change the predicate to `[@id=2]` to get the set of `child` nodes for the next `Parent`.

However, if you ignore the `Parent` node altogether and use:

```
//child/@name
```

you can select `name` attribute of all `child` nodes in one go.

```
name="Child_2"
name="Child_4"
name="Child_1"
name="Child_3"
name="Child_1"
name="Child_2"
name="Child_4"
name="Child_3"
```

Comment: Yes ... but the question is how to return only the attribute value: `Child_2` etc. The reason I'm here is I managed to get as far as you got, I want just the attribute values, I used Google, and arrived at this question.

Comment: @reinierpost It depend the xml engine in use if you see here http://xpather.com/VZDuaXsb  and in javascript its just `node.text` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35726551/3057246

Answer (score 8):

You should use `//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/data(@name)`

The attributes can not be serialized so you can't return them in an xml looking result. What you need to do is obtain the data from the attribute using data() function.

Comment: data() function on an attribute gives the error "XPath error : Invalid expression" in xmllint.

Answer (score 6):

```
//Parent/Children[@  Attribute='value']/@Attribute
```

This is the case  which can be used where element is having 2 attribute and we can get the one attribute with the help of another one.

Answer (score 6):

for all xml with namespace use local-name()

```
//*[local-name()='Parent'][@id='1']/*[local-name()='Children']/*[local-name()='child']/@name
```

Answer (score 4):

@ryenus, You need to loop through the result. This is how I'd do it in vbscript;

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("kids.xml")

'Remove the id=1 attribute on Parent to return all child names for all Parent nodes
For Each c In xmlDoc.selectNodes ("//Parent[@id='1']/Children/child/@name")
    Wscript.Echo c.text
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the standard formula to extract the values of attribute and text using XPath-

1. To extract attribute value for Web Element-

   **elementXPath/@attributeName**
2. To extract text value for Web Element-

   **elementXPath/text()**

In your case here is the xpath which will return

```
//parent[@name='Parent_1']//child/@name
```

It will return:

```
Child_2
Child_4
Child_1
Child_3
```