# Finding attribute value using lxml without using a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
>>>p = []
>>>r = root.findall('.//*div/[@class="countdown closed"]/')
>>>r
'<abbr data-utime="1383624000" class="timestamp"/>'
>>>for i in r:
            s = i.attrib
            p.append(s['data-utime'])
>>>p
['1383624000']
```

s yields:

```
{'class': 'timestamp', 'data-utime': '1383624000'}
```

I think the code above is verbose(creating a list, using a for loop for only 1 string).

I know lxml is capable of achieving this more succinctly however I am unable to achieve this, I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Without a pointer to a document containing the content you're querying against, it's hard to test an answer for correctness / compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XPath, not the ElementTree `findall()` (which is a more limited and restricted language present for compatibility with the ElementTree library lxml extends), and address your path all the way down to the attribute:

```
root.xpath('//html:div[@class="countdown closed"]/@data-utime',
  namespaces={'html': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})
```

(It *is* possible to use namespace wildcards in XPath, but not great practice -- not only does it leave one open to namespace collisions, but can also be a performance impediment if your engine indexes against fully-qualified attribute names).

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to find just one element, use `.find()`, not `.findall()`:

```
r = root.find('.//*div/[@class="countdown closed"]/')
if r is not None:
    p.append(r['data-utime'])
```

`element.find()` returns `None` if no match is found, or the element. If you are certain that the element is always present, you can omit the `if r is not None` test.

Because you are using lxml, you can use the [`element.xpath()` method](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) to use a more powerful XPath expression that what mere ElementTree methods can support. You can add a [`/@attribute-name` attribute selection element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835891/how-to-extract-attribute-s-value-through-xpath) to the path to select the attribute value *directly*:

```
attr = root.xpath('.//*div[@class="countdown closed"]/@data-utime')
p.extend(attr)
```

`.xpath()` returns a list as well, but you can just use `p.extend` to add all contained values to `p` in one step.