# Get id from parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

I have XML file, here part of it:

```
<advcampaign_categories>
    <category id="85">Sport</category>
    <category id="79">Gifts</category>
    <category id="87">Flowers</category>
    etc..
</advcampaign_categories>
```

and try to parse it like this:

```
url = 'my_xml_str' 
data = open(url).read
 Hash.from_xml(data).each do |k, v|
v['advcampaign_categories'] ...
```

then it returns me:

```
{"category"=>
  ["Sport",
   "Gifts",
   "Flowers"]
}
```

So my question is how to get `category_id`? if its possible or may be any other solutions?

Ideally, I want hash like this `{sport:85,gifts:79}`

Comment: There is no `category_id` in your XML sample. Do you mean you want the `id` parameter from the `<category>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy with a library that supports xpath (nokogiri for instance)

[xpath exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835891/how-to-extract-attribute-s-value-through-xpath)