# How to get an attribute from a root tag using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to parse through the below XML and get the value of attribute "RefNum". I used the both XPath but still no luck.

1. `//*[local-name()='ExternalBidAward']/[@RefNum]/text()`
2. `//*[local-name()='ExternalBidAward'][@RefNum]/text()`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExternalBidAward
    BidAwardType="INITIAL"
    ContractRefNum="1111"
    ContractType="GPO"
    CustRealmNum="1024"
    CustomerRefNum="1234566"
    CustomerRefType="CUST"
    StartDate="2016-01-01 00:00:00"
    EndDate="2018-10-11 23:59:59"
    PubDate="2018-10-11 17:32:22"
    RunDate="2018-10-11 17:30:02"
    PubRefNum="00001111111"
    RefNum="0028383101"
    >
  </ExternalBidAward>
```

Comment: Why are you using this construct, `*[local-name()='ExternalBidAward']` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract value of attribute node via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835891/extract-value-of-attribute-node-via-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

If no namespace is involved:

```
/ExternalBidAward/@RefNum
```

Should get you what you want.