# How to extract the value of an HTML attribute using scrapy response.xpath?

Tags: shell, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the value of the attribute `data-asin-price` inside a `<div>` tag

Which in the example below you can see is **22.63**

```
<div id="cerberus-data-metrics" style="display: none;" data-asin="B079GMRZ8S" data-asin-price="22.63" data-asin-shipping="0.0" data-asin-currency-code="AUD" data-substitute-count="-1" data-device-type="WEB" data-display-code="Asin is not eligible because it is not enabled"></div>
```

Is there any way to do this using response.xpath() with scrapy?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract value of attribute node via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835891/extract-value-of-attribute-node-via-xpath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wanted to post the answer I found.

To get the **22.63** value our of the `data-asin-price` attribute in scrapy shell I did the following:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id = "cerberus-data-metrics"]/@data-asin-price').extract_first()
```

Cheers

Comment: Nice work answering your own question. For clarity, I edited your question and your answer. You are actually trying to extract the value of an attribute, not an element. An HTML/XML element is the tag and everything in it. The attributes are things like `style`, `id`, and `href` and their values that appear in the opening portion of the tag. Knowing this will help you find answers in the future.

Comment: @pwinz thank you for the edit and clarification. It will definitely help me in the future. Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of `scrapy` (v2.8), you can also use its [built-in extensions to CSS selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors). These extensions may also be available in earlier version of `scrapy`.

```py
response.css("div::attr(data-asin-price)").get()
```

In its generic form, replace `CSS_SELECTOR` and `ATTRIBUTE_NAME` as needed.

```py
response.css("CSS_SELECTOR::attr(ATTRIBUTE_NAME)").get()
```

Comment: NOTE: I recognize that the OP asked specifically about XPath's. This question, however, was the top Google result when I generically searched for extracting HTML attributes using `scrapy`, and I find this CSS answer *much* easier to read.