# How to get all the atributes from a `<circle>` element in a website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to get the positions `cx` and `cy`from `<circle>` elements using selenium in python, but I haven't found any way to do it. That is how the website and the HTML looks like:
[image]

Does anyone know how to get all the `cx` and `cy` values from all the circles within the `<g>` in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_attribute`

```
cx,cy = [],[]
circle = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('circle')
for i in circle:
    cx.append(i.get_attribute('cx'))
    cy.append(i.get_attribute('cy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from ["Extract value of attribute node via XPath"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835891/extract-value-of-attribute-node-via-xpath):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("path/to/circle/element/@cx")
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath"path/to/circle/element/@cy")
```

---

Update: response to comment

For selecting all cx-attributes, use something like this:

```
path_to_circles = "//div[@class='g-act'/div/div/div/svg/g/g/circle"
cx_values = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path_to_circles + "/@cx").extract()
cy_values = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path_to_circles + "/@cy").extract()
```

Then you probably also want to change the values from string to float:

```
cx_values = [float(cx) for cx in cx_values]
cy_values = [float(cy) for cy in cy_values]
```

And probably turn them into list of pairs (i.e. [(50.23, 115.36), ...]):

```
values_from_graph = list(zip(cx_values, cy_values))
```

Note that I didn't test the code so please excuse me for any typos :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you tell me how I can get the path to the circles elements?

Comment: @scraper No problem, I've updated the answer to better answer your comment