# Alternative ways of getting xpath attributes? Safari doesn't support /@. Must work with document.evaluate

Tags: xpath, safari

I am basically in the same situation as this question [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath) and the solution in that question works for me in Chrome and Firefox **BUT** I have to use Safari (for a couple of different reasons, mainly AppleScript) and using `/@` in Safari returns an empty result.

Are there alternative ways to extract xpath attributes?

They/it must be compatible with `document.evaluate`. (I have a solution that works with `$x` but it doesn't work with `document.evaluate`, adding `.map(link => link.href)` at the end of the xpath).

---

**Update**: it seems I am partially wrong - `@/` does indeed work in all cases I have tried but mine.

More details to reproduce my problem: On https://www.facebook.com/zuck/followers I want to extract the link to all the followers. The element I target looks like this:

```
<a class="x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g xt0b8zv" href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100065103331942" role="link" tabindex="0">
```

A simple xpath (I will optimise it later) that points to this element:

```
//div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a
```

As you can see the a has four attributes, `class`, `href`, `role` and `tabindex`.

If I add `/@class` at the end of my xpath it evaluates to

```
class="x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g xt0b8zv"
```

just as expected. Adding `role` or `tabindex` as the end also gives the expected result but if I try with `href` instead of the other three attributes, I just get `href` (the actual string) as result. Or, it is even weirder and hard to describe in just text:

**Collapsed result**
[image: Collapsed result]

**Expanded result**
[image]

#### I interpret this as Safari is treating the string `href` differently from other XML attributes? Can this really be true? Workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the link elements with `document.evaluate`, then extract the `href` DOM properties as shown below:

```
var links = []; var xpathResult = document.evaluate('//div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a', document, null); var link = null; while ((link = xpathResult.iterateNext()) != null) { links.push(link.href); } ; links
```

Comment: Any suggestion as to why this workaround is necessary?

Comment: @MichaelKay, I haven't been able to tell from d-b's questions why sometimes `$x` is used and later it has to be `document.evaluate`; I only know that `$x` returns an array so you can use e.g. `.map` on it while it doesn't work with `document.evaluate`. And I am afraid those screenshots of browser console output don't allow me to tell whether Safari has some quirk accessing the `href` or any attribute using `$x` and/or `document.evaluate`. It appears something is odd or quirky in that context but I have not tried to research or even verify what it is exactly.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The background is that I controlling Safari using AppleScript, which requires document.evaluate. Yes, it does indeed seem to be a quirk with Safari and href. Another question: what does the single `links` at the end of your expression do? Just curious, I suck at JS...

Comment: @b-t, from what I assumed the evaluation of JavaScript in Safari needs some result returned by the final statement and that is just my attempt to have the `links` array declared at the beginning with `var links` and initialized with `var links  = [];`, then filled by the `links.push(link.href)` in the while loop to be returned as the final result of the JavaScript evaluation. I would think that a sole attempt to finish the sequence of statements with the while loop would not show you any result, unless that AppleScript evaluation exposes JavaScript variables like `links` automatically.