# How to modify my xPath to get the a href?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I use this xPath

```
$url = extractNodeValue('//*[@id="coremain"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a', $xPath);
```

to get the link from this HTML

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com" class="summary url" style="color: rgb(198, 35, 35);">Name of the link</a>
```

However instead of getting the link, I get the appearead name for the link. How can I fix this?

Comment: extractNodeValue is not a built-in PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the attribute of href attribute not the nodevalue:

```
'//*[@id="coremain"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/@href'
```

Comment: Well the attribute has a nodevalue, too. Se he want's to get the nodevalue, just from a different node. And better than giving back just the codez is providing reference IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what `extractNodeValue()` actually does (and you have not shared the code), however by its name it extracts the node-value. And the node value of the  `<a>` element is

```
"Name of the link"
```

So you should specify the node instead of which you want to retrieve the value of. The `<a>` element is normally known as link, so no clue what you mean. Probably the *`href` attribute*?

See as well:

- [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-from-xpath)

*Edit:* I see now the changed title, you are indeed interested in the `href` attribute. It works as outlined in the link above, just prefix the attribute name with the `@`-symbol to make clear you are looking for an attribute:

```
.../a/@href
```

This is looking for the `href` attribute of the `<a>` element. Elements in Xpath are parent of the attributes they have. But the attributes are no children. ?! This is different to the DOM, see as well:

- [5.3 Attribute Nodes - XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#attribute-nodes)