# Issue with Xpath expression to extract an attribute when another attribute is a match

Tags: xml, xpath

my first question here!

So I'm using the following expression:   //nodes/node[@name='00_QATEST']

and the XML is like this:

```
xml version 1.0
    <nodes>
        <node id = "1234abc" name="00_QATEST"/>
        <node id = "12345abcd" name="00_QATEST2"/>
```

When I use the above expression it will return the whole block. I need to get just the id value. Now if I do put id instead of node in the above expression I get nothing returned.

Comment: Did the whole example of your XML come through in the post?

Comment: No weird, let me see how I can fix it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting attribute using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is selecting the entire node because you've only selected //nodes/node... That is, you're selecting the entire node, and not just fetching the ID.

Instead, try adding //@id to select only the ID of the node with the correct name.

```
//nodes/node[@name='00_QATEST']//@id
```

Also you might like to check out: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Edit:
I tested your xml with the following code:

```
<nodes>
    <node id = "1234abc" name="00_QATEST"/>
    <node id = "12345abcd" name="00_QATEST2"/>
</nodes>
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Using your expression I get "ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: Extra illegal tokens: '@', 'id'" when using that link to test it and pasting my XML there. Not sure why, is it the spaces that's doing it?

Comment: Seems like it's nto a good xml the way it's being generated. After pressing fix and reissuing the expression you mentioned now I'm getting "ERROR - Seem like XML is not well formed:Element type "node" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."

Comment: Copy/paste the //nodes/node[@name='00_QATEST']//@id part into the "XPath" field, and copy paste the XML I put in the edit into the XML field, then hit Test.

You should get a result of "1234abc"

Comment: Here try this (This resmbles more the actual data im referring minus some confidential data replaced)  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes>
  <node id = "acf-123-asd" name="Demo" childcount="3"  type="{http://www.test.org/model/content/1.0}folder" noderef="workspace://SpacesStore/acd89f98-976a-4538-892b-2a1fc91adedf"isD3ReadOnlyAdmin="true"/>
  <node id = "6f71-asd-123" name="Demo2" childcount="47"  type="{http://www.test.org/model/content/1.0}folder" noderef="workspace://SpacesStore/86921580-6f71-4b18-b88d-550f7f3a642d" isD3ReadOnlyAdmin="true"/>
</nodes>

Comment: Using the above with the expression you mentioned results in ERROR - Seem like XML is not well formed:Element type "node" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: There are some spacing issues and other issues with the xml you pasted. If I clean it up and change my XPath to //nodes/node[@name='Demo']//@id the result I get is 'acf-123-asd', as you'd expect it to be. So I think you need to inspect your source XML more closely.

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark your question as answered if I helped you any. Cheers :)