# Getting attribute using XPath Mozilla Firefox fails recent version

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, xpath, mozilla

A user asked this a while ago. Why not work on the latest versions of Mozilla?

[Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Given an XML structure like so:

```
<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I'm using this expression:

```
path="/bookstore/book/title/@lang";
```

It works on Google Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer, Safari. But not in Mozilla Firefox. Only happens with attributes (@ or attributes::).

I tried in Mozilla 6 and works perfect, but not in Mozilla 33 or 34

Comment: Please include a code sample showing the failure. http://jsfiddle.net/1yer552a/ works fine for me with Firefox 34.

Comment: Works fine for me, too, Firefox 34. Please substantiate your claim. Also, the unabbreviated XPath axis is `attribute::`, not `attributes::` - a typo?

Comment: Perhaps the data is in an HTML DOM rather than an XML DOM, in which case the browser inserts elements to try and "repair" your HTML?

Comment: and how exactly do you run xpath in Mozilla Firefox?