# Get href attribute of a tag with id using XPath

Tags: xpath

How do I get the Xpath that returns:

```
//www.example.com
```

With the following DOM:

```
<a id="myId" href="//www.example.com">
Click here</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting attribute using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath) (based on question title, it should be something like `/a[@id='myId']/@href`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//a[@id='myId']/@href
```

That should work, just implement it into whatever language you're using xpath with.

Comment: If this question gets closed (I marked it as duplicate before you answered), sorry about the loss of points. It was a good first answer. +1 Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: No worries! I appreciate the heads up!