# How to get a parameter as a result of a search condition from a XML-File?

Tags: java, web-services, parsing, data-retrieval, pattern-finding

Im getting via Webservice an XML File and now I want just to get certain data out of it by finding a certain match in the same tag:

For example: < Person name="Peter" age="33" />

Now I want to find the name Peter and get his age returned. Maybe a general solution for "if this xml-tag contains this then give me that out of it". Im really not sure how to do that, maybe tokinizing it or something like that but i couldnt figure it out. Does someone have an idea? -- Code is written in Java!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath

Comment: Which XML parser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XPath to extract the specific tag with a condition. Like

```
"/Person[@name='Peter']/"
```

[Refer this article for how to use XPath in Java.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)

Comment: Unfornutanetly still didnt get it to work

My Code: 
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/example.xml");

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("some expression");

String res = expr.evaluate(doc);

But no matter what I dont get anything returned :S