# Select node with attribute case insensitive via XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I would like to search node via Xpath case insensitve.

```
<Validation>
    <Presentation>
        <Slide Tag= "Test">
            <FontSize Value = "36"/>
        </Slide>
    </Presentation>
</Validation>
```

I've used this code

```
String xPath = string.Format("/Validation/Presentation/Slide[lower-case(@Tag)='{0}'][1]", "test");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
```

but it throws an XPath Exceptions: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: When you used XPath :).  But seriously, is there a reason not to use XDocument here?

Comment: Your answer is here 
Getting attribute using XPath
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath

Comment: @bilal yes, but i need also case insensitive..

Answer (score 10):

.NET doesn't support XPath 2.0.

So you can use this abomination:

```
    /Validation/Presentation/Slide[translate(@Tag,
   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')= 'test']
```

(I hard coded your value in for ease of testing with XPathBuilder.)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this? 
INFO: Use XPath to Perform a Case-Insensitive Search with MSXML:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315719

use `translate`

```
doc.DocumentElement.selectSingleNode("/Validation/Presentation/Slide[translate(@Tag, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'test']")
```

Answer (score 5):

`lower-case` is XPath 2.0 function and .NET itself supports only Xpath 1.0 expressions, so you can't use it this way.

Alternatively you can use Linq2Xml:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"your_file_Name");
var node = doc.XPathSelectElements("/Validation/Presentation/Slide")
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("Tag") != null 
                                    && String.Equals(x.Attribute("Tag").Value, "test",
                                                 StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```