# what is the xpath for getting specific link in google sheet? (a href)

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, hyperlink

The source that I want to get the xpath is:

```
<a href="Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=s6Wglwrt63gs90VwQ1uN%2bQ%3d%3d&amp;rt=2&amp;let=6&amp;ct=0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvList_ctl02_urlHTML" target="_blank" class="URLTitle">
<span id="ReportList_Title_468175">
                                            اطلاعات و صورت‌های مالی میاندوره‌ای  دوره ۶ ماهه منتهی به ۱۳۹۷/۰۳/۳۱ (حسابرسی شده)</span>
</a>
```

When I write this XPath:

```
//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvList_ctl02_urlHTML']
```

It returns the name of the cell but I want the link of the cell. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: I want this one in the source: Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=s6Wglwrt63gs90VwQ1uN%2bQ%3d%3d&rt=2&let=6&ct=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this hope will help you:

```
//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvList_ctl02_urlHTML']/@href
```

Comment: Happy to help you. Please accept answer if it's really help you to achieve your desired output.