# Retrieve specific part of XML tree value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

Have an Xml.XmlNodeList variable "xmlNodes", populated with data.  The   xmlNodes(0).InnerText contains the following:

```
<InitializePagedPull ShowCode="AR13dfD">
   <TokenInfo PageToken="293845657-32-47" TotalRecords="1" PageSize="20" TotalPages="1" />
</InitializePagedPull>
```

I'd like to get the TokenInfo.PageToken  value... without having to use some archaic method of "string.indexOf() string.substring(x,y)"

I've tried creating a child XmlDocument based on the current xmlNodes(0).InnerText... and then using GetElementsByTagName("TokenInfo")... which gets me a little closer... but I'm still unable to easily grab the PageToken value within.

Comment: Can you use xpath?

Comment: @JackFleeting If I knew what it was, or how... probably :-P  Quick google tells me it's like RegEx but for XML ?

Comment: No, it's far, far more than that, and it's not at all like regex (fortunately...). If you can use xpath (see for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation), a simple one line expression will extract your token.

Comment: Do you want vb.net or c#?

Comment: @djv Either one... easy to swap back and forth... but already got an answer below :-)

Comment: @adam yes, that works. You can still check out serialization which allows you to model your data with concrete classes to give you strong-typing. You can make a model of your entire xml file and deserialize into classes to access any property much more simply.

Comment: @djv Absolutely, once I get the basics working I plan on cleaning it up with full blown objects , mapped for each field , etc...   baby steps, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that is using XPath is still archaic.
It is already more than a decade since LINQ to XML rules them all.
Here we go.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(@"<InitializePagedPull ShowCode=""AR13dfD""><TokenInfo PageToken=""293845657-32-47"" TotalRecords=""1"" PageSize=""20"" TotalPages=""1""/></InitializePagedPull>");
    string pageToken = xml.Descendants().Attributes("PageToken").FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
```

Comment: Never used LINQ to XML before, always good to learn new things - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [XPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation) you can query the xml document to pull out information you want.

```
string xml = @"<InitializePagedPull ShowCode=""AR13dfD""><TokenInfo PageToken=""293845657-32-47"" TotalRecords=""1"" PageSize=""20"" TotalPages=""1""/></InitializePagedPull>";

// Load the XML into an XmlDocument
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

// Using the query "/InitializePagedPull/TokenInfo/@PageToken" we can pull out the @PageToken attribute
var pageToken = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/InitializePagedPull/TokenInfo/@PageToken").Value;
```

Comment: Giving this a try, will report back soon!

Answer (score 1):

Using XML serialization,

Create classes which represent your data

```vb
<Serializable>
Public Class InitializePagedPull
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property TokenInfo As TokenInfo
End Class

Class TokenInfo
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property PageToken As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property TotalRecords As Integer
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property PageSize As Integer
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property TotalPages As Integer
End Class
```

Then assuming your xml is an XElement,

```vb
Dim xml = <InitializePagedPull ShowCode="AR13dfD">
              <TokenInfo PageToken="293845657-32-47" TotalRecords="1" PageSize="20" TotalPages="1"/>
          </InitializePagedPull>
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(InitializePagedPull))
Dim pull = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(xml.CreateReader()), InitializePagedPull)
Dim pageToken = pull.TokenInfo.PageToken
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to retrieve an xml attribute value.
I had a quick search and found this, any help?
[Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Answer (score -1):

Probably there is a namespace related things. You can try with a LocalName property instead of name.