# What's wrong with this xpath statement?

Tags: xpath

Trying to get the color WHITE out of the line of code.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="itemAttr current" title="WHITE" data- 
value="WHITE"><img src="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product- 
pic/Clothing/2019/06/05thumb-img/1559762268621192281.jpg"></a>
```

I've tried this:

```
color = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//p[@id="select-attr- 
 0"]/a[@href="javascript:void(0)"]@title""").click()
```

I get this error message:

> The string
>   '//p[@id="select-attr-0"]/a[@href="javascript:void(0)"]@title' is not
>   a valid XPath expression.

What I want is to get `"WHITE"`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing a `/` before the `@title` attribute. Try this xpath instead:

```
//p[@id="select-attr-0"]/a[@href="javascript:void(0)"]/@title
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to [get an attribute value of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath), you need to put '/' before the '@title', so the following should work (provided the parent element **p** is correctly addressed):

```
//p[@id="select-attr-0"]/a[@href="javascript:void(0)"]/@title
```

When working with XPATHs, it is often useful to use one of free online testers to get instant path feedback, e.g. [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below xpath snippet.

> //p[@id='select-attr- 0']//child::a[@value='WHITE']