# How do I extract only the url from this element?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

What xpath should i use to extract only the url link from the below element?

```
<a class="url" rel="noreferrer" onclick="redirect('https://www.fotbollskanalen.se/allsvenskan/kujovic-siktar-pa-startplats-var-naturligt-att-agera-inhoppare---nu-vill-jag-s');">Läs mer på Fotbollskanalen</a>
```

I have tried using the below xpath, but it only returns "Läs mer på Fotbollskanalen" and not the url itself.

```
a[1]/child::node()
```

Also tried different versions attempting to set specify the class but unable to get it right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//a/@onclick, "'"),"'")
```

It will,

- `substring-before(substring-after(foo, "'"),"'")`:
  Get in everything enclosed by `'` in `foo`.
- `//a`: Of the element a.
- `/@onclick`: Inside the attribute `onclick`.