# xpath TypeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object is not iterable

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

About as simple as it should get:

```
<state name = "foo1>
    <foobar item1="something1" item2="somethingelse1" item3="usefulitem1"/>
    <foobar item1="something2" item2="somethingelse2" item3="usefulitem2"/>
<state name = "foo2">
...
root = lxml.etree.parse(fileName)
path = "./*[contains(text(),'useful')]"
someElement = root.xpath(path)
```

I'm trying to make a list of all the foobar's that have some item with the text 'useful' somewhere in it. I keep getting the error TypeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object is not iterable

Comment: Still not a [mcve]. The "XML" is not even well-formed.

Comment: Sorry, when I open my XML that is what I see. I don't know how much more minimal I can get

Answer (score 3):

I actually thought you would be able to XPath from a tree object. Huh. But you definitely can't iterate over it. To do that you need to get the root (element).

From the docs:

> [getroot(self)](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html?highlight=getroot#lxml.etree._ElementTree.getroot)
> Gets the root element for this tree.

So your code would look something like this instead.

```
<state name = "foo1>
    <foobar item1="something1" item2="somethingelse1" item3="usefulitem1"/>
    <foobar item1="something2" item2="somethingelse2" item3="usefulitem2"/>
<state name = "foo2">
...
```

```py
tree = lxml.etree.parse(fileName)
root = tree.getroot()
path = "./*[contains(text(),'useful')]"
someElement = root.xpath(path)
```

The tricky thing is that when you use `.fromstring` instead of a file then you automatically have the root element, rather than an `ElementTree`.

Comment: But I agree that your xml file looks weird. I would have expected something more like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath?rq=1

Comment: `tree.getroot()` is not needed. The `xpath()` method is available on both `Element` and `ElementTree` objects.