# Xpath to find attribute value for a particular element value using local-name()

Tags: xslt, xpath, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a payload like mentioned below.

```
<A xmlns:com="http://www.example.com/xml/xmlns/example">
    <B>
        <X appCode="001">xxx</X>
        <Y appId="0002">yyy</Y>
    </B>
    <C>
        <D>
            <E>
                <F id="1" code="001">test-1</F>
                <F id="3" code="002">test-2</F>
                <F id="4" code="003">test-3</F>
                <F id="5" code="004">test-4</F>
            </E>
        </D>
    </C>
</A>
```

I need to get the **id value** for A/C/D/E/F['test-2']. Also, I have to use local-name() to avoid namespaces.
Tried the following and get the below result.

> //* [local-name() = 'C']/* [local-name() = 'D']/* [local-name() =
> 'E']/* [local-name() = 'F']

```
<F id="1" code="001">test-1</F>
<F id="3" code="002">test-2</F>
<F id="4" code="003">test-3</F>
<F id="5" code="004">test-4</F>
```

How to find the id value of 'test-2' which is 3?
*(NOTE: I'm using this in wso2 EI property mediator)*

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Comment: I have gone through this post before. It's not what I'm searching for. I needed to get the attribute value for a given element value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, given your example, the expression:

```
//*[local-name() = 'F'][. = 'test-2']/@id
```

will return `3`.

However, it needs to be said that namespaces are to be used, not avoided. Declare the namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix, and use the prefix to address the elements.

Note also that in the given example, the namespace declaration is entirely redundant. You could use simply:

```
"//F[. = 'test-2']/@id"
```

or a bit more efficiently:

```
"/A/C/D/E/F[. = 'test-2']/@id"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Regarding namespaces, it can vary in the payload, so I need to disregard it. Thanks a lot for your support!!