# How do I select the value of an ID element in XPath?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

Given an XML with the following set up:

```
<eCrow.CrowGroup CorrelationID="ec367934-e7bd-4213-b0e5-d149c57eec61" > 
    <eCrow.01>fu</eCrow.01> 
    <eCrow.02>bar</eCrow.02> 
    <eCrow.03 CorrelationID="bfe7d35b-bbc1-4591-8d0d-9d42252039bc" >03003</eCrew.03> 
</eCrow.CrowGroup>
```

How do I manage to get XPath to select the CorrelationID from within the node header: `<eCrow.CrowGroup CorrelationID="ec367934-e7bd-4213-b0e5-d149c57eec61" >`, NOT the CorrelationID from `eCrow.03`.

In regards to the link suggestion, I am probably doing something wrong but `//eCrew.CrewGroup/*@CorrelationID` just selects the entire node.

Comment: You have a typo in your XML, the closing tag for `eCrow.03` is named `eCrew.03`.

Comment: The XPATH expression to CorrelationID Is `/eCrow.CrowGroup/@CorrelationID`, see: [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Comment: (1) Is  it a c# or SQL Server question?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.

As already mentioned in the comments, I had to fix your XML to make it well-formed.

XQuery `.value()` method gives you the answer.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<eCrow.CrowGroup CorrelationID="ec367934-e7bd-4213-b0e5-d149c57eec61">
    <eCrow.01>fu</eCrow.01>
    <eCrow.02>bar</eCrow.02>
    <eCrow.03 CorrelationID="bfe7d35b-bbc1-4591-8d0d-9d42252039bc">03003</eCrow.03>
</eCrow.CrowGroup>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/eCrow.CrowGroup/eCrow.03/@CorrelationID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS CorrelationID
    , @xml.value('(/eCrow.CrowGroup/eCrow.03/@CorrelationID)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') AS CorrelationID2;
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|         CorrelationID          |            CorrelationID2            |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| bfe7d35b-bbc1-4591-8d0d-9d4225 | BFE7D35B-BBC1-4591-8D0D-9D42252039BC |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You should probably just change the data type to `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: @Charlieface, good point, but it will make the output upper cased. Not sure if the OP needs that.

Comment: No it won't, it will make it a Guid, which is 16-byte binary data. The client app is free to format that how it likes

Comment: Let's wait for the OP reply.

Comment: @Charlieface, In the meantime I updated the answer to show both options.