# Scrapy Chained Xpath Selection

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am use the following xpath selector within the parse method of a scrapy spider

```
  for item in response.xpath(
         '//div[@id="mosaic-provider-jobcards"]//a//*[boolean(@id)]'
        ):
     print(item.get())
```

This works and returns the following text for each item extracted

```
<span title="bla bla bla" id="1211">sdsd</span>
```

Within in the loop I now want to extract title and id (i.e. bla bla bla and 1211), I attempted the following code but this is not working

```
  for item in response.xpath(
         '//div[@id="mosaic-provider-jobcards"]//a//*[boolean(@id)]'
        ):
        print(direct_page.xpath(".//title").get())
```

This returning None, I want it to return the title for every span, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have to use @title check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath

Answer (score 0):

use `@title`

```
direct_page.xpath('//span/@title').get()
```