# I need to extract the alt element using Xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, extract

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09zRq.png)

I am using this xpath

```
//*[@class="relative mr3"]//div[2]//img/alt/text()
```

to extract

```
"Tramontina Primaware 18 Piece Non-stick Cookware Set, Steel Gray"
```

however I am getting empty excel cell.

Comment: Please share your source code whatever you have tried. It will help us to come up with a proper solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Comment: Please supply your XML as code in the body of your question, not as an attached image. That way (a) we see everything in one place, (b) we can try it out for ourselves, and (c) the code will still be available when someone reads this in ten years' time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some difficulty reading your code because of a poor colour scheme, but my suspicion is that you've fallen into the common trap of thinking that "//div[2]" means "the second descendant div" whereas it actually means "every descendant div that is the second div child of its parent".

Answer (score 1):

The value of a attribute `alt` is not found with `img/alt/text()` but just with `img/@alt`

Try this XPath:

```
//*[@class="relative mr3"]/div[2]/img/@alt
```